# How to model a one to many relationship in Django

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, one-to-many

in my current Django project I have list of players and a list of games and I'm looking for a Django field to store the information in which games the player participate. To give an example: User 1 played Game 1, 2, 3, and User 2 played 2, 3... 
Since not all players of a game are registered, I'm not looking for the relation game to player. So, I'm looking for something like an one-to-may field (player to several games).

So far, I found the ForeignKey field. However, when I add this to game, I can only store one player not several player ids. Or do I missed something?

How do I express my problem in Django model fields?

Comment: You add a `ForeignKey` in the opposite direction.

Comment: The relationship you are describing is a many-to-many: a user can play many games and a game can be played by many users. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1):

As far as One user can participate in different games and one Game can contain several users you may need **ManyToMany** relation.
You can add users as a **ManyToMany** field to `Game` model:

```
users = models.ManyToManyField('User')
```

in order to add user to a game you can do:

```
game = Game.objects.get(...)
user1 = User.objects.get(...)
user2 = User.objects.get(...)
users = [user1, user2]
game.users.add(*users)
```

If you want to see all users of particular game:

```
game = Game.objects.get(...)
game.users.all()
```

If you want to see which games a particular user participated:

```
user = User.objects.get(...)
user.game_set.all()
```